# Boolean switch for conditional statement after its definition?

Tags: conditionals

I'd like to use conditional statements in my preamble file and then define the value of the Boolean variable *afterwards*. The reason is that I import the preamble.tex first thing in my main file where I then want to specify switches as appropriate. I've tried this with the plain tex \newif and with the etoolbox packages, yet both seem to require the value of the Boolean variable *before* the definition of the conditional. This appears to mean that I would have to change my preamble.tex, defeating the purpose of making it a separate file.

Is there an easy way of achieving this, short of splitting the preamble file in two parts?

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: You can use `\iffoo` in macros defined in your preamble that are executed later but clearly if you put them at the top level so they are evaluated when the file is input, they must be defined at that point. That is not a restriction of plain tex or etoolbox, just a fact of life.

Comment: do you mean, you want to have `\foofalse` in your config file, and then `\input{config}` followed by `\newif\iffoo` in your document?  this is such an odd idea, i must surely be misunderstanding...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is there maybe a way of overriding default values? Similar to package options set after their definition?

Comment: It mostly depends on what your "conditional definitions" look like. Can you add a couple of examples?

Comment: @wasteofspace What I have in mind is \newif\iffoo in my preamble.tex. I then input this in my main.tex, followed by \footrue. This way I would not have to touch the preamble file but could specify the Boolean values in my main as appropriate.

Comment: @egreg What I tried is

Comment: @Michael Don't add code in the comments, but rather in the question. However, the simplest way out is to put `\input{preamble}` *after* having defined and set the conditionals.

Comment: @egreg What I tried is to specify different headers/footers depending on the type of document I write, e.g. using fancyhdr in preamble.tex: \iffoo \rhead{Michael's report} \else \rhead{} \fi. Yet this does not work if \footrue is given in main.tex after preamble.tex has been input.

Comment: @Michael Of course it doesn't work. How can TeX know what's the value of `\iffoo` if you don't tell it?

Comment: @egreg Yes, but this would mean splitting my preamble file in two parts, the first of which would contain \newif statements and would be input first. Then I would set my Booleans, and import the second part of the preamble with the conditional definitions afterwards. I was hoping I could keep all commands in one preamble file.

Comment: @egreg I understand \if statements may not be appropriate for this purpose. Yet see my comment to David Carlisle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The approach you're following is not correct. The best thing is to change `preamble.tex` into `preamble.sty` and use options.

### File `preamble.sty`

```
\ProvidesPackage{preamble}
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}

% The following defines \ifpreamble@foo (\if<packagename>@<optionname>)
\DeclareBoolOption[true]{foo} % specifying `foo` is the same as `foo=true`

\ExecuteOptions{foo=false} % foo is false by default

\ProcessKeyvalOptions{preamble}

\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\ifpreamble@foo
\fancyhead[R]{Michael's report}
\fi

\endinput
```

### File test.tex (`foo` enabled)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[foo]{preamble} % or \usepackage[foo=true]{preamble}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\section{A}
\kant
\end{document}
```

### File test.tex (`foo` disabled)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{preamble} % or \usepackage[foo=false]{preamble}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\section{A}
\kant
\end{document}
```

Comment: This exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!!